# C++ while loop, using if else statements to count in an array

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm having trouble with a basic c++ program assignment, and would greatly appreciate any help. The assignment is as follows:

Write a program that accepts input from the keyboard (with the input
terminated by pressing the Enter key) and counts the number of letters (A-Z and a-z), numerical digits (0-9), and other characters. Input the string using cin and use the following looping structure to examine each character in the string with an "if" statement and multiple "else if" statements.

My program thus far is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char s[50];
int i;
int numLet, numChars, otherChars = 0;

cout << "Enter a continuous string of       characters" << endl;
cout  << "(example: aBc1234!@#$%)" <<      endl;
cout  << "Enter your string: ";
cin  >> s;

i = 0;
while (s[i] != 0) // while the character does not have ASCII code zero
{
if ((s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') || s[i] >= 'A' && (s[i] <= 'Z'))
  {numLet++;
  }
else if (s[i] >= 48 && s[i] <= 57)
{numChars++;
    }
else if ((s[i] >= 33 && s[i] <= 4) || (s[i] >= 58  && s[i] <=64) ||  (s[i] >= 9 && s[i] <= 96) || (s[i]   >= 123 && s[i] <= 255))
  {otherChars++;
  }
  i++;
}

cout  << numLet << " letters" << endl;
cout << numChars << " numerical characters" << endl;
cout << otherChars << " other characters" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

The letter count gives a value a little too low, and the number count gives a large negative number. Other chars seems to function fine.

Comment: For numerical characters you can use `'0'` and `'9'`; notice the single quotes, which differentiate between text representation and numeric (internal) representation.

Comment: Check your logic.  Do you **need** an `if` statement for the *other* characters or would a final `else` statement work?

Comment: Also, use `std::string` and `std::getline`.  If somebody enters more than 50 characters, your program will start writing beyond the character array, causing *undefined behavior*.  Otherwise, use `std::getline` and specify the maximum number of characters (remember to reserve room for the terminating '\0' character).

Comment: Also, the condition `(s[i] >= 33 && s[i] <= 4)` can't happen.  Try out some test cases that make this condition true.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, you need to initialize your variables, but you have also an error in this code:

```
if ((s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') || s[i] >= 'A' && (s[i] <= 'Z'))
```

the brackets are wrong. And as a result, you are not counting lowercase letters (i think) anyways it shoul be this (indented for visibility):

```
 if (
      (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') ||
      (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
      )
```

you can also use [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/). Since you're using c++ and not c, right ;) (people here get mad about the difference apparently)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set each integer to 0. As it is, your code only sets `otherChars = 0`. Make that line `numLet = 0, numChars = 0, otherChars = 0;`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, it now works as intended.